# How to determine delete date of an email in Exchange Online

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app

We are using Exchange Online as part of our Office 365 subscription/deployment. Clients are using OWA and Outlook 2016 client for Exchange access.

As part of a legal dispute we are trying to determine the date that a user deleted specific emails. I have found the emails using eDiscovery and copied them to a Discovery Mailbox.

The question is: is there any way to determine what date and time the user deleted a specific email?

NB: From a Google search it appears that the best Exchange can do is give the last modified date but as this could be something other than deletion it won't stand up in court. So what I need is a definitive way to prove the date and time of the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, Exchange doesn't record that information - last modified is the best that is available.